# check if jquery is bind with checkbox

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have created a checkbox with default value to checked .for example

```
<input type="checkbox" value="1" checked="checked" />
```

but when I refresh page then checkbox is toggled from check to uncheck. may be it is with jquery but I have included many files of jquery.

> So Is there any way to find the right file or right jquery which is
>   attached with input box.

Comment: There might be some code in your script which is unchecking checkbox.

Comment: Yes may be so how I can find that script?. Because I have multiple files

Answer (score 0):

When you add a checkbox in your code,by default it is having unchecked state. If you want to check whether it is checked or unchecked, you can check it by below jQuery code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    if($('input[type="checkbox"]').is(":checked")){
        alert("Checkbox is checked.");
    }
    else if($('input[type="checkbox"]').is(":not(:checked)")){
        alert("Checkbox is unchecked.");
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Actually Op asked ->`So Is there any way to find the right file or right jquery which is attached with input box.`? So answer this

Comment: Yes I can make it checked with jquery but I want file or jquery which is responsible to make it checked

Comment: then you need to manually search it in your whole website code.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code at the end , I hope will help you.

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('load', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Op asked-`So Is there any way to find the right file or right jquery which is attached with input box.`? so answer this

Comment: I think you should check manually by removing one by one jquery files, but seems to be time taking if you have used many many jquery files. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

use it like this

```
<input type="checkbox" value="1" checked/>
```

it will remain checked all the time

Comment: Op asked:- `So Is there any way to find the right file or right jquery which is attached with input box.`?

Comment: From his question it appears that, his main concern is, during refresh his checked input get back to unchecked state